# What is the difference between an Autobot and a Decepticon

Tags: transformers

The title 'Autobot' is explained to be the short version of 'Autonomous Robotic Organisms'. Wouldn't that mean all Cybertronions are Autobots? Why then do the good "Heroic Bots" lead by Optimus Prime call themselves Autobots while the bad "Evil Bots" lead by Megatron call themselves Decepticons? Aren't they all the same race?

Comment: Autobots have better PR and Marketing departments.

Comment: It all boils down to politics...

Comment: @DVK Thanks big dog.

Comment: I just ran across this piece of the puzzle; In the original animated series continuity, the Decepticons owe their warlike ways to their faction's origin as military hardware robots, created by the five-faced aliens, the Quintessons, while the Autobots were designed as consumer goods. I'm not sure what is considered 'canon' in the Transformer universe but this seems to make sense.

Comment: The most logical explanation is that "Autobots" is the original name, and they consider themselves the real autobots, and Megatron et al are the bad ones deserving of a different name. Kinds of like if some Americans called the bad guys traitors, and themselves Americans, even though they technically both are.

Comment: @JamesChristopher - yes, that's very close to the comic continuity, I believe. All were originally Autobots - the Decepticons split off from them.

Comment: @morgan, Anything not fan-created is "canon", it's just an issue of there being multiple continuities and canons. The new ["aligned" continuity](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Aligned_continuity_family) is Has/Tak's attempt to sort out the huge mess that's been made over the years. It doesn't make any of the older continuities less "canon", it just tries to find a way to mesh them together as best as possible.

Comment: @Morgan just noticed I posted the same answer as you. If you want to post your Answer I can delete mine.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty - No that's cool. You found that independently and deserve the rep for the work. If you could expand on it even more that would be great. As phantom42 points out, the canon seems to be a quagmire so if you could trim up or combine a few more stray aspects of this question, you will actually be helping the process of establishing accepted canon. This site is that influential. It's on your shoulders now. "Lets roll".

Comment: Answer: About $4

Comment: "the Decepticons owe their warlike ways to their faction's origin as military hardware robots, created by the five-faced aliens, the Quintessons, while the Autobots were designed as consumer goods" Which side would a Nokia phone transformer be?

Comment: @JamesChristopher: “The most logical explanation is that "Autobots" is the original name, and they consider themselves the real autobots, and Megatron et al are the bad ones deserving of a different name.” *Or* the Decepticons chose that name as a rejection of the overbearing and morally bankrupt ideologies of the dominant Autobot class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The rise of the term *Autobot* differs with each continuity.

**In the Aligned continuity** (which is the most similar to the Michael Bay movies), the term Autobot is coined by Orion Pax as a description for the concept of abolishing the caste system that the Cybertronians were living under, not as a description for the race as a whole. "Autonomous" as in deciding one's fate by themselves.

**In the IDW comics continuity** the Autobot moniker is given to the corrupt Cybertronian Empire by the galaxy's other races to describe these mechanical beings. Auto from automatons, because in the other races' eyes the Cybertronians were long lived mechanicals who never changed in any fundamental way (despite the name Transformers). When both Optimus Prime and Megatron rise up against the corrupt government, Megatron chose to name his faction with a new name and a new sigil, while Optimus decided to repurpose the term Autobot and derive it from "autonomous" (from the people, by the people) and keep the old sigil. Which, in essence, displays the philosophical differences between the two leaders.

**In the 1984 cartoon continuity** the two races were created separately by the Quintessons. Autobots as consumer grade machines, and the Decepticons as weaponized machines. So this makes this continuity the only one were the Autobots and Decepticons were never the same race.

**In the Marvel comics continuity** the Autobots were created by Primus and lived more or less peacefully on Cybertron. When Megatron started his revolution he decided he needed to differentiate his faction, and so gave them a new name. As far as I recall, no reasoning is given for the names.

**In the Dreamwave comics continuity** the two factions arose when Megatron started the civil war. Those who sided with Megatron named themselves Decepticons, and those who sided with Sentinel Prime and the Council of Ancients named themselves Autobots. Again no reasoning is given for the names.

Comment: It seriously helps to have this info concisely collected onto one page.

Comment: @Morgan - I point you to the excellent and well maintained http://www.tfwiki.net. Transformers *writers* have been known to consult it.

Comment: Oh great. That's all I need, another website to burn up endless hours searching and sifting through :-).

Answer (score 13):

Originally for toy reasons.

The Autobots were all cars in the original run in 1984, so Automobile-Robots.
Decepticons because they are the bad guys.

[Bob Budiansky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Budiansky) is crediting with naming the first batch of guys if I remember correctly.

Comment: While not an in-universe answer, this is potentially interesting and useful.  However, could you provide any references about Bob Budiansky's role in naming Autobots/Decepticons?  [This wiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Bob_Budiansky) mentions many individual characters, "Dinobots", and other mythos elements (like the Autobot Matrix) named by him, but not specifically "Autobots" or "Decepticons".  If you could provide a reference, this would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: This is good stuff @Rigas, definitely worth expanding upon.

Comment: @Beofett I can't find a written reference, I beleive I heard in and interview/panel that given at a Botcon, but some of the old school guys who where there at the beginning.
Like a lot of things back then It was never written down and directly credited in official documents, but being as the guy was there I was inclined to believe him.

Answer (score 8):

The Transformers were created by a race called the Quintessons.

They originally created Autobots as general worker consumer bots and Decepticons as military weapons. The Transformers eventually became sentient and rebelled.

This is far back in their past though. The more recent factions are more political centric. It is not uncommon for an Autobot/Decepticon to switch sides.

Comment: Good information, but would be much better if you could source it....

Comment: Autobots- consumer grade machines:

Optimus Prime- a Kenworth K100 cab over truck, then a Peterbilt Semi-tractor (truck);

Bumblebee- a yellow Volkswagen Beetle, then '77 Camaro, then prototype 2008 Camaro;

Ironhide- a black 72' GMC, then a GMC C4500 4x4 Crew Cab TopKick; 

Sideswipe- Chevrolet Stingray Concept;

Decepticons as weaponized machines:

Megatron- a size changing Walther pistol w/scope, a Cybertronian Jet, a cybertronian tank;

Starscream- a McDonnell Douglas F-15 Eagle, a Lockheed Martin F-22 Raptor;

Devastator- M1 Abrams Tank;

Bonecrusher- Buffalo Armored Vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Japanese naming is an interesting contrast (especially as TF started as a rebrand of two completely separate line of Japanese toys).

The Japanese name for the Autobots is (literally) Seibertron (or Cyberton) - so Cybertronion is seen as synonymous with the "good guys".

The Decepticons on the other hand are known as Destron (from destroy/destruct) - an obvious anti-faction there.

Answer (score 1):

Autobots have blue eyes or optics; Decepticons have red. (At least, that's what I noticed in the 80's cartoon series - apart from their insignias) Therefore, blue is good, while red is rude